# How to find specific shortcodes in a post or in a widget and pass them to a variable?

Tags: shortcode

I've created a shortcode in my plugin and I used it in some pages. Now I have to get the attributes of these shortcodes on the posts that includes the shortcode.

A sample shortcode is [book id="432"]. I have to get this 432 value when I write this shortcode into a post or a widget.

I see this function in order to get an attribute from a shortcode string:

```
function get_shortcode_atts( $tag, $text ){
    preg_match_all( '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/s', $text, $matches );
    $out = array();
    if( isset( $matches[2] ) )
    {
        foreach( (array) $matches[2] as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $tag === $value )
                $out[] = shortcode_parse_atts( $matches[3][$key] );
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

It's ok. But before this what should I do, in order to **detect a shortcode and get it** from a post or i widget?

There is a function named `has_shortcode` but I think it's not enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear from the question what exactly you're trying to do. Is there multiple shortcodes per page? Are you on the page when you need to get the book id?

If you're on the page with the shortcode, then this function would return an array of book id's:

```
function book_id() {
    return preg_match_all( '/(?<=\[book id=").+?(?="])/', get_post()->post_content, $match )[0];
}
```

If post content was `[book id="432"][book id="434"]` this would return:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "432"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "434"
}
```

If there is only one book id per page, you could use `preg_match` rather than `preg_match_all` and the function above would return a string rather than an array.